# The SKSpriteNode called runner is moving in the opposite way

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I have an SKSpriteNode called runner and whenever I touch the screen to try to drag it from one place to another, runner goes the opposite way? For example, if I try to drag it left, it goes right, if I try to drag it up then it goes down. Adding TouchesEnded did not help. Can anyone look at my code and tell me why this is happening please?

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import SpriteKit

    class Maze: SKScene {

        let runner = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
        {
            self.createRunner()
        }


        override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
        {
            let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
            let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
            runner.position = location
        }

        override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
        {
            let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
            let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
            runner.position = location
        }

        func createRunner()
        {
            runner.setScale(0.50)
            runner.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
            runner.name = "RunnerNode"
            self.addChild(runner)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried a lot of variations of it on different simulators. Do you have any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: Maybe try using `locationInNode()` instead of `locationInView()`? `locationInNode()` is specific to SpriteKit.

Comment: Jonathan Dharmesh Kheni Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine:

```
    import SpriteKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    let runner = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        self.createRunner()
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        runner.position = touchLocation
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        runner.position = touchLocation
    }

    func createRunner()
    {
        runner.setScale(0.50)
        runner.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        runner.name = "RunnerNode"
        self.addChild(runner)
    }
}
```